# Supersymmetry Perturbation Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, supersymmetry, perturbation-theory, ground-state

Source:[Mirror Symmetry](http:////www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01c.pdf) p.198

I have the Hamiltonian
$$H = \lambda\bigg( \frac{1}{2} \tilde{p} + \frac{1}{2}h''(x_i)^2(\tilde{x}-\tilde{x_i})^2 + \frac{1}{2}h''(x_i)[\overline{\psi}, \psi] \bigg) + \lambda^{1/2} (\cdots) + (\cdots) + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^{-1/2})\tag{10.157}$$

where the leading term is

$$H_0 = \frac{1}{2}p^2 + \frac{\lambda^2}{2} h''(x_i)^2 (x-x_i)^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}h''(x_i) [\overline{\psi}, \psi]\tag{10.158}$$

which is the Hamiltonian of the supersymmetric harmonic oscillator and therefore the ground states are:

$$\Psi_i = e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}h''(x_i)(x-x_i)^2} \left\vert 0\right> + \cdots \ \text{if} \  h''(x_i) > 0\tag{10.159}$$
$$\Psi_i = e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}\vert h''(x_i)\vert(x-x_i)^2} \overline{\psi} \left\vert 0\right> + \cdots \  \text{if} \ h''(x_i) < 0,\tag{10.160}$$
where the +... represent the subleading terms in $\lambda^{-1/2}$.

And now to my question:
The author says that one can find the subleading terms so that the energy is strictly zero to all orders in  $\lambda^{-1/2}$, by inserting the expansion of the potential $$h(x) = h(x_i) + \frac{1}{2 \lambda}h''(x_i) (x-x_i)^2 +...$$
into
$e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}h} \left\vert 0\right>$ or $e^{\frac{\lambda}{2}h} \overline{\psi} \left\vert 0\right>$
but i could not see it.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained on p. 193-194. For $h^{\prime\prime}(x_i)\neq 0$ there is precisely one ground state (i.e. normalizable wave function with zero energy.)
It is always a Gaussian function. The signature$^1$ of $h^{\prime\prime}(x_i)$ determines whether the ground state is proportional to $ \left\vert 0\right>$ or to $\overline{\psi} \left\vert 0\right>$.

--

$^1$ The square of $h^{\prime\prime}(x_i)$ in eqs. (10.157) & (10.158) are typos. Also there are implicitly written  proportionality constants in eqs. (10.159) & (10.160).